# Performance OracleJDK or OpenJDK

Tags: linux, performance, debian, java

I am forced to using Java on my server and I am having a headache installing Java. I have an automated deployment script which installs the software and needs to be run to reinstall the server regularly in the cloud.

I am so stuck on which route to go down. **So my question is, am I right to be concerned about the performance of OpenJDK**? I am using this for a SOLR search server.

**The current three options**

```
OpenJDK7
 - Easy to automate install
 - Fairly fast
 - Fairly stable

Sun JDK6
 - Easy to automate install
 - Fairly fast
 - Fairly stable

Oracle JDK7
 - Nearly impossible to automate install
 - Fast 
 - Stable
```

**REFERENCES**

A. http://opengeo.org/publications/geoserver-production/

[image: Performance]

B. http://research.geodan.nl/2012/10/openjdk7-vs-oracle-jdk7-with-geoserver/

[image: Performance 2]

C. http://blog.gonzih.me/blog/2013/04/14/clojure-on-raspberry-pi-openjdk-vs-oracle-java-8/

Comment: In JDK7, the implementation code of OpenJDK 7 and Oracle JDK 7 is nearly identical in all but a very limited number of cases, primarily to do with desktop-things (media coding and such). There is no reason that I can fathom that OpenJDK 7 would be slower than Oracle JDK 7.

Answer (score 4):

No need for compromises!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

There are also development builds of Java 8 available.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: How reliable is this third party plugin repo though? I can't help but get the feeling that one day it just wont be there and it will break my production site

Comment: It's been around for about a year so far ([Original Announcement](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)) and still kicking strong. You're right in that like any 3rd party PPA, it may go offline or stop getting updates; I would definitely keep a mirror of the repo to be on the safe side to guard against the site going down, and re-evaluate your solution if Oracle breaks the packages by moving links or something. Easily installing Oracle's JDKs is a pretty big thing, so I'd imagine that someone else would take up the mantle quickly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to go is to use this sites repository as it can also update your Oracle Java without a hitch. 
http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php
Their repository is for Debian and derivatives.

cheers
Roesjka